# Spacer() swiftui leaves a white space

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently building a UI that has a big red 250px height box on the top that holds information and a scrollview underneath it. I build this all in a VStack(). I put a spacer() at the bottom of the VStack to push everything to the top of the screen. But it has a big white space between the red container at the top and the scrollview. Even though both don't have any padding(). Does anyone know how this is possible? This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct User: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ...
                code
                ...
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250)
            .background(Color.red)
            .ignoresSafeArea()

            // somehow it has a white space here...

            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 2) {
                    ForEach((0...56), id: \.self) {_ in
                        Image("testimage")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0))
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                         }.padding(.bottom, 75)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    .padding(.top, -10)

                }
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
               // this Spacer should push everything to the top
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }  
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
}
```

Edit:
To make my question better understandable I made this summery:
I have build a VStack with 2 items in it. there is a big white space between the two and I don't know how to get rid of this white space. If I remove .ignoresSafeArea() the white space disappears. The thing is I need .ignoresSafeArea() to push the first item in VStack up. Does anyone know what I can do to keep .ignoresSafeArea() but get rid of the white space?

I added a screenshot of the problem. I gave the scrollview a green background so that the white spacing between the VStack and the Scrollview is visable.

[image: Screenshot of the example]

Comment: We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What platform are you on? Using `NavigationView` with two children does pretty dramatically different things depending on what platform/device you're on. Unrelated hint: change `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250)` to `.frame(height: 250)` and try to avoid using `UIScreen` whenever possible.

Comment: @Yrb I added a small summery to try to make it better understandable.

Comment: @jnpdx I removed the UIScreen. Thanks for your feedback! I do need navigationView because I have a button in it linking to another view

Comment: I didn’t ask whether you needed it - I said it behaves differently on different platforms, so it would be helpful to know what platform you’re on.

Comment: I'm on the iphone platform. I'm not making it for ipad or macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by putting the VStack and the Scrollview in an other VStack in the navigationView. Then I put the .ignoresSafeArea() on this new VStack.

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct User: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // new VStack that includes the topbar VStack, the 
            // scrollview and has the .ignoresSafeArea() on it.
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    ...
                    Code topbar
                    ...
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 250)
                .background(Color.red)

                Scrollview {
                    ...
                    Code scrollview
                    ...
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }          
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to embed everything in a VStack with 0 spacing.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct User: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello World!") //Easier to test
                }
                .frame(height: 250) //Dont use UIScreen
                .background(Color.red)
                .ignoresSafeArea()

                // somehow it has a white space here...

                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 2) {
                        ForEach((0...56), id: \.self) {_ in
                            Image("testimage")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0))
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                             }.padding(.bottom, 75)
                            
                        }
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                        .padding(.top, -10)

                }
                
                 Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you might need to give the ScrollView a max height to push it upwards. `.frame(maxHeight: 175)`

As you haven't given a reproducible example or an image. I cant tell you for certain what will work

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I tried it but it didn't work. I added a screenshot so that the problem is more clear. It has something to do with .ignoresafeaear(). Without it there is no whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Arnavs Answer is correct.
Notice:
When you are trying to implement multiple Views on one page, 90% of the time it is better to have them in one H/V/Z-Stack.

For a better understanding start a new project and try ...

```
Navigationview{
    VStack{
      Text("Hello Vertical World")
      Text("Hello Vertical World2")
    }

    HStack{
      Text("Hello Horizontal World")
      Text("Hello Horizontal World2")
    }
}
```

and the same thing but "different"

```
    NavigationView {
      VStack{
        Text("Hello Vertical World")
        Text("Hello Vertical World2")
        HStack{
            Text("Hello Horizontal World")
            Text("Hello Horizontal World2")
        }
    }
}
```

I can't double check bc i am on my phone, but this should look very different.

Comment: I didn't no that thankyou! unfortunately it doesn't fix my issue.